# Finding the centroid of the region bounded by two curves

Tags: calculus, integration, moment-generating-functions

I am trying to find the centroid ($\bar{x}, \bar{y}$) of the region bounded by the curves:
$$y = x^3−x$$ 
and 
$$y = x^2 − 1$$

I've tried this a few times and can't get to the correct answer. I feel like I'm missing something, like I have to account for an offset perhaps.

So far I've gotten $A = 4/3$ by integrating $\int_{-1}^1 (f(x)-g(x)) dx$.

The limits of integration from $-1$ to $1$, based on a graph of the 2 functions.

$\bar{x} = 4/5$ via 
$$\frac{1}{A} \int_{-1}^1 (x(f(x)-g(x))dx,$$ 
and 
$\bar{y} = -12/35$ via 
$$\frac{1}{A} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{2}(f(x)^2-g(x)^2)dx$$

This is a homework question but it's only worth one point and I've finished the rest so I'm more asking out of wanting to know what I've done wrong. I've had a few almost identical questions that I had no problem with.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to MathSE. I strongly recommend you to write mathematics in this site using MathJax. [Click here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial

Comment: Your **x bar** calculation looks wrong.  It should be negative (sketch the curves) and dividing by $A$ should remove the $4$.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I was able to find my mistake. Henry you were right. I looked at it again and got  a negative for x bar (-1/5).